# What the reason of TS error and how to fix it?

Tags: typescript

I have type IApiMethod and interface IApiRest. Typescript compiler says me:

> Property 'index' of type 'IApiMethod | undefined' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'IApiMethod'.(2411)

If I delete `[key: string]: IApiMethod` in IApiRest interface the error goes away.

I don't understand why `[key: string]: IApiMethod` breaks code

```
export type IApiMethod = (
    api: any,
    params?: Record<string, unknown>,
    options?: Record<string, unknown>
) => Promise<any>

export interface IApiRest {
    index?: IApiMethod,
    create?: IApiMethod,
    update?: IApiMethod,
    delete?: IApiMethod,
    view?: IApiMethod,
    [key: string]: IApiMethod,
}
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] the title so it is more specific to the issue. ② Optional properties by default allow `undefined`, so the index signature must match that to compile; the easiest way to do that is to make make it `[key: string]: IApiMethod | undefined` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzDGrN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your comments!

Yes, that fully address the question

Comment: Oh well, I would have written up an answer but I see one has already appeared.  I'll disengage now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index signature `[x: string]: IApiMethod` breaks your code because the keys that are already defined in the `IApiRest` interface don't match that signature.
`index?, create?, update?, ...` are all defined as optional keys which means they can have a value of `undefined`. 
Now, when you add an index signature of `[x: string]: IApiMethod` you say that all keys of that interface must be of type `string` and the corresponding value cannot be `undefined` as you didn't define them as such.

What you can do to avoid the errors is exactly that: Define the index signature as optional. You can do that by defining the type of the value of the index signature as a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the actual value and `undefined`.

```
type IApiMethod = (
  api: any,
  params?: Record<string, unknown>,
  options?: Record<string, unknown>
) => Promise<any>;

interface IApiRest {
  index?: IApiMethod;
  create?: IApiMethod;
  update?: IApiMethod;
  delete?: IApiMethod;
  view?: IApiMethod;
  [x: string]: IApiMethod | undefined;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkggmAlgWQsAFgewCZQLxQAUAUFFAIZIBcFAdiADSlRjkBO5AtgM4D8NAJQgBjTG2wAebsDaJaAcwZQArrQDWtTAHdaAPiZlMYYIky0+gkWMnTZCpao3a9xAJT5dUAAptMnRNwQEuT0ugDcxMRywBBsAGbkwtDwSELSUADezHLYEAAe-LAIKGhY2BFkwmwQ5DGFKSUYOBUqYNi1EPXFqE3lzLkANmidNA09ZS0AbogQWl1I483MANp5NLZy8gC6o92lOFAAPiq0uXFyEH0AvkA)

---

Another thing you could consider is using an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) (because you cannot have mapped keys on Interfaces) if you have certain other keys you want to have required.

```
type IApiMethod = (
  api: any,
  params?: Record<string, unknown>,
  options?: Record<string, unknown>
) => Promise<any>;

type AdditionalKeys = "share" | "follow";

type ApiRest = {
  index?: IApiMethod;
  create?: IApiMethod;
  update?: IApiMethod;
  delete?: IApiMethod;
  view?: IApiMethod;
} & {
  [K in AdditionalKeys]: IApiMethod;
};

declare const api: ApiRest;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkggmAlgWQsAFgewCZQLxQAUAUFFAIZIBcFAdiADSlRjkBO5AtgM4D8NAJQgBjTG2wAebsDaJaAcwZQArrQDWtTAHdaAPiZlMYYIky0+gkWMnTZCpao3a9xAJT5dUAAptMnRNwQEuT0ugDcxMSgkFBw2NiIJmbkADYA0hAg3PhQAETc6OwQuVAAPnkAZpgpKdq5EVHg0AiIQtI5AN7MctgQAB78sC2oGDgRZMJsEOTAEIPwSCNY2OMqYNgzczQLKGjLq70paFtDi3tjzABuiBBa88PnK8QAvlAAZFBdZADaaVBysXiiVMtFSGSyAF1tg9Rk9ng1esIUkUoKJzMAKNRYkg2sAwkA)